# multi-language site with multiple locales misbehaviour

Tags: php, locale

In a project of my company there is a website available in 6 languages. The site sends some emails to customers/members. Every phrase/word is stored in database and all work well in the website. Our main problem appears in emails.

In each email there are daily reports. We use set_locale() to define each language and "show" the day names (months also) to the proper selected language. This works ok.

In some cases there are more than one emails to be send (in 2 different languages) - here we have problem.
Every info in email appears correct - texts/translations from database.
Day names (and month also) appear only in the first language in both emails.
So, if the first email was in german and the second in french, the french email will have everything in french excpet the day names that will be in german (even though that we execute set_locale again before sending the second email)

Why is that? Is this some set_locale bad behavior? How can we prevent/fix this? Thank you for any insight/tips

**EDIT:**
the code we use is: setlocale(LC_ALL, $setLocale);
where setLocale would look like "fr_FR.UTF8"

Comment: As `setLocale()` is not thread-safe, inconsitencies can occur under load. Is your webserver under high load when this happens?

Comment: you're using `setlocale()` arguments allowing time right? Without seeing some of the code it'd be hard to say what specifically is the problem.

Comment: @S Morgan: i have added the set locale part in my question

Comment: @phpdev i havent noticed the load of the server. Just that this "bug" occurs when we send 2 emails in different languages. Is it possible that set_locale can be set in each thread? If thats the case then i don't think there is anything we can do

Answer (score -1):

you should use this module (from Zend Framework): http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.html
it is really useful to identify the browser context language.

For translations you can use Zend Translate:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html

It is really useful!

Comment: we do not wish to change our scripts/logic. We simply ask how we can correct/improve the current ones